# R "object x not found error" in calling self-defined function

Tags: r

I used the following function to remove the lowest-ranked data (marking them as NA):

```
RemoveOutlier<- function(x, pctl){
          qnt <- quantile(x, probs = pctl)  
          y <- x
          y[x <= qnt] <- NA
          y
       } # remove the bottom pctl% data
```

For example, `RemoveOutlier(x=seq(1,10,1), 0.1)` will remove the bottom 10% of data.

Then I tried to apply this function to `iris$Petal.Width` by `Species`, generating a new column `Petal.Width.Rm`:

```
iris$Petal.Width.Rm <- with(iris, ave(Petal.Width, Species, FUN = RemoveOutlier(x, 0.1)))
```

But I had the error object 'x' not found. What's the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
> iris$Petal.Width.Rm <- with(iris, ave(Petal.Width, Species, FUN = function(x) RemoveOutlier(x, 0.1)))
> head(iris)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Petal.Width.Rm
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa            0.2
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa            0.2
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa            0.2
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa            0.2
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa            0.2
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa            0.4
```